# Zend Studio: How to copy files to local server automatically when testing?

Tags: php, copy, local

I just installed Zend Studio and it seems pretty great. But I would like to be able to copy my files from my dev folder to my local server's htdocs folder whenever I debug or run the solution.

I am already able to copy files to my remote server automatically on every save. I would imagine I should be able to do this automatically too for my local server?

Please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess I could just save my project files directly into the htdocs folder?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you don't try to save copies to multiple locations.  Check out the Subclipse plugin and use SVN to deploy a copy of your code to your dev server instead of copying it in between servers.